# JQuery FancyBox overlay color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox-2

I have tried to get a Fancybox iFrame to load automatically and to give the overlay a different color.
So far so good on the autoload.

Got it working.
The color I couldn't get to change.

Now I tried several examples many listed here. But I guess I am doing something wrong.

In my head code I am loading :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();

    // Change title type, overlay closing speed
    $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            'overlayColor'             :        '#ec2d2d',

            title : {
                type : 'outside'
            },
            overlay : {
                speedOut : 30,
                css: {
                    'background-color': '#ec2d2d'
                },
            },
            overlayColor: {
                css: '#ec2d2d',             
            }
        }
    });



    $("#hidden_link").fancybox().trigger('click');

});  
</script>
```

And my HTML is like this :

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" id="hidden_link" href="iframe.html" title="HOI">Iframe</a>
```

It opens onload. But I cannot get the overlay to turn red.

What am I missing here?
I have tried as you see several options. But none used the right way.

TIAD

**Edit:**

When I try to add this code:

```
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            beforeShow : function() {
                $('.fancybox-overlay').css({'background-color' :'#ec2d2d'});
            }
```

I seem to make a mess of the Syntax. Because it doesn't respond to this script. But I am clueless of how to do this correctly.

This is what I got now:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            beforeShow : function() {
                $('.fancybox-overlay').css({'background-color' :'#ec2d2d'});
            },
            helpers: {
                title : {
                    type : 'outside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedOut : 30,
                    css: {
                        'background-color': '#ec2d2d'
                    },
                },
                overlayColor: {
                    css: '#ec2d2d',             
                }
            }
        });

        $("#hidden_link").fancybox().trigger('click');
    }); 
</script>
```

Also adding the CSS code makes no difference:

```
        #fancybox-overlay{
        background-color:#ec2d2d !important;
    }
```

Could it be that there is another JS file loaded that overwrites all of my settings??

These are the libraries loaded:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>
```

Comment: Seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/jRsjK/6720/

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the background color before showing of fancybox.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow : function() {
        $('.fancybox-overlay').css({'background-color' :'#ec2d2d'});
    }
});
```

and then remove `.fancybox()` from `$("#hidden_link").fancybox().trigger('click');`

Just like this it'll work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the overlay color in CSS

```
#fancybox-overlay{background-color:#ec2d2d !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the overlay alone,

```
$.fancybox.helpers.overlay.open({parent: $('body')});
```