# Fancybox - customize the background color of an onload popup image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

I'm using the fancybox iframe to display HTML files. The home page has a button to launch the iframe. The iframe has a red background (in the css I changed .fancybox-skin to background: #f00;). Thanks to the [advice of Travis J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148076/fancybox-javascript-to-detect-mobile-orientation-and-launch-advisory-pop-up-if), I now also have a fancybox pop-up image, that launches when the home page is loaded by a mobile in portrait mode and advises that the site is viewed better in landscape. The pop-up image is a PNG... with transparency. Here's the PNG: http://www.casedasole.it/testing/popup.png

The problem. Please open this page in landscape mode: http://www.casedasole.it/testing/popup3.html, and click on the "Launch iframe" button. Nice red background. Then adjust to portrait (just squeeze a desktop browser into vertical) and reload, and there's the "transparent" PNG - with the same #f00 background as the iframe.

To make the PNG background really transparent, I can make fancybox-skin's background: transparent, but then the iframe also takes the transparent background: http://www.casedasole.it/testing/popup4.html

The code is:

```
var isPortrait = window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight;
if( isPortrait )
{
 $.fancybox.open([
   {
    href : 'popup.png'
   }
  ], {
   padding : 0
   }
 );
}
```

How can I persuade fancybox to make an exception for popup.png and give it a transparent background?

---

From here down is 30 hours later. Logged in as myself, there is no "Your Answer" textbox, and no trace of the "[Answer your own question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/)" checkbox. So...

**GOT IT!**
After some fiddling, found the solution. In the css, I left fancy-skin background transparent, so the pop-up image has it's transparent background. Then, from the answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888432/jquery-fancybox-overlay-color), I changed the settings for the launch button to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
 modal : true,
 maxWidth : 800,
 maxHeight : 420,
 autoSize : true,
 autoWidth: true,
 autoHeight: true,
 fitToView: true,
 padding : 0,
 margin : 0,
 showCloseButton : true,
 scrolling : 'no',
 beforeShow : function() {
         $('.fancybox-skin').css({'background' :'#f00'});
    },
 afterShow : function () {
 $('.fancybox-skin').append('<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:jQuery.fancybox.close();"></a>');
 }
 });});
```

That way, the iframe gets its red background.
Here it is: [www.casedasole.it/testing/popup6.html](http://www.casedasole.it/testing/popup6.html). I hope some visitor from the future finds all this useful.